# Connecting to a Windows machine with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to simply connect to a machine and run the win_ping module.

There are several tutorials online that outline a few key steps:

- Create a directory `./windows`
- Create a file `hosts` in `./windows`
- Create a directory `./windows/group_vars`
- Create a file `windows.yml` in `./windows/group_vars`
- Insert several variables with your Windows credentials into `windows.yml`

The problem is that none of these actually specify where to put these relative to the '.'.  I've tried placing this structure in `/etc/ansible/` and unfortunately it's looking like Ansible isn't picking this up at all.  I've also tried moving the structure around but no luck.

How do I get Ansible to reference the directory I've created?  I believe `ansible.cfg` would make sense but I can only see how to point it to a default inventory file. Interestingly enough - even adding a group called 'windows' in the base hosts file and calling ansible with the group there - it says no hosts found. I have also uncommented the inventory location in ansible.cfg to point to `/etc/ansible/hosts` and it still says no hosts found when calling `ansible windows -m ping` (or `win_ping` for that matter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two places where Ansible looks for `group_vars` subdirectory:

- the playbook directory - the one containing a playbook you run
- the inventory directory - the one specified with `-i` option at run time, or a default one (usually `/etc/ansible`, or `/usr/local/etc/ansible`)

In most typical scenario you might place `group_vars` along with the `playbook.yml`.

The example you posted uses the second method, so to reference the files you need to add `-i` to the command:

```
ansible windows -m ping -i ./windows
```

Comment: thanks for this response.  It fits the bill for my specific question so marking as answer.  This link also has the definitive answer regarding variable processing for those interested!  http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#group-variables

Answer (score 0):

There are a few GitHub repos regarding Ansible best practices, and I've found [enginyoyen/ansible-best-practices](https://github.com/enginyoyen/ansible-best-practises) helpful not only in your case but also to understand the playbook/inventory/role/task differences in a full-blown Ansible project.

Some highlights: (`/` refers to the **project's** home directory)

- Your variables do indeed go in `/group_vars/`

  - `/group_vars/windows.yml` will be automatically read by hosts you assign to the windows **group**
  - `/group_vars/db.yml` will be automatically read by hosts you assign to the db **group** and so on
- You may also include files with names like `/host_vars/win_host_1.yml` which will be read only by that host
- The groups from `/group_vars/` are defined in your inventory file**s** (plural)

  ```
  [windows]
  win_host1.example.com
  win_host_2.example.com
  ```
- Inventory files have names like `/production.yml` and `/staging.yml` to help ensure code in different states of readiness is deployed to (ideally) identical environments.

Other highlights not directly answering your question

- A *role* is a file made of the *tasks* required to do something, like install `nginx`. They have names like `/roles/install_nginx.yml`
- Playbooks have names like `/playbooks/win_hosts.yml` which do nothing but match the *groups* from your inventory files with the *roles* you want hosts in those groups to run.
- **When you run `ansible-playbook` your `$HOME` should be  `/playbooks/`** so that the different inventory files are referred as `ansible-playbook -i ../production.yml win_hosts.yml`
- This is also the place to put a custom ansible config file, `/playbooks/ansible.cfg`
- There's also a way to manage *external* roles from Ansible Galaxy or GitHub and keep them separate from custom roles you built, but still in your project directory instead of `/etc/ansible/roles/` where `ansible-galaxy` puts them by default.
- A nice little bash script to install Ansible